# Dynamicly updating GItlab CI verdict

Tags: shell, gitlab

I’ve written this code in my CI .yaml file to put a hard limit for number of warnings. basically I created a varaible for number of warnings and I compare to it.
The problem now : I want That when someone decreases the number of warnings. the CI updates the variable in the YAML file to the lesser value and merge it.

Is this possible to be done via git lab CI or the merge train ? May be It is possible to make the CI update the .YAML file and merge it with the changes ? or may be there is a way to share a variable across the CIs and update it from the CI ?

My code:

```
variables:
 WARNING_LIMIT: 326

………………….....////// Some code


- exit_code=0; make -j 8 xyz -C build 2>&1 | tee build_output.txt || exit_code=1
- if [ `grep “error:” build_output.txt | wc -l` -ne 0 ] ; then exit_code=2 ; fi;
- if [ `grep “warning:” build_output.txt | wc -l` -gt $WARNING_LIMIT ] ; then exit_code=3 ;fi;

- if [ $exit_code -eq 3 ]; then echo “Make command  target warning limit exceeded”; fi;
```

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/ `You can use predefined CI/CD variables or define custom:

    Variables in the .gitlab-ci.yml file.
    Project CI/CD variables.
    Group CI/CD variables.
    Instance CI/CD variables.`. Do `Project CI/CD variables`  solve your problem?

Comment: If the variable is defined in the ci yaml file - then the only way it can be changed by a user is if they change it in that file - so why would you need the CI system itself to also change it?

Comment: I want the CI to automatically updates the verdict. For example If my limit is 10 warnings and I added a fix and decreased them to be 9 warnings and merged that fix to the master.I want the limit to be updated to be 9 warnings. Otherwise the following merge to the master branch is allowed to introduce 1 new warning.